# How to send KDE5 desktop notification from a bash script?

Tags: command-line, notification, kde5

I've tried a number of options, **none** of them worked:

```
notify-send 'text'
kdialog --passivepopup 'text' 5
qdbus org.kde.knotify /Notify event "event" 'app' "(" ")" 'title' 'text' 'pixmap' '' 5 0
```

Update: first two options should work, in my case the problem is a KDE bug with autohiding panel: [KDE5 popup notifications not shown if panel is autohidden](https://askubuntu.com/q/738005/20275)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

On my install of Kubuntu 15.10 and KDE neon, `notify-send` command was not available until I installed the **libnotify-bin** package.

After installing **libnotify-bin**, `notify-send` works fine:

```
sudo apt-get install libnotify-bin
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, maybe I deleted some package or disabled some service, but in my case it just returns exit status 0 and I don't see any notifications.

Comment: Perhaps check if libnotify4 is also installed? This was already present on my system but may have been a dependency from some other package.

Comment: Installed, the latest version `0.7.6-2svn1`

Comment: @DavidFoerster This is clearly an attempt to answer the question.

Comment: Looks like none of notification popups work at all on my main installation. I'll recheck on a default installation.

Comment: Filed this bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kde-runtime/+bug/1547752
Can you please verify that kdialog option works for you?

Answer (score 24):

At least first two options should work, I just have a problem with notifications in KDE in general: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kde-runtime/+bug/1547752

```
notify-send 'text'
kdialog --passivepopup 'text' 5
```

Comment: Very helpful re. kdialog! I couldn't get notify-send's `urgency=critical` to work!

Answer (score 4):

first 'notify-send' did not work for me. But when I enabled 'notifications' widget (/icon or whatever) in Tray, it worked.

Try enabling the Tray `notifications` applet.

Answer (score 2):

In my case: I was in **Do not disturb** mode and had forgotten about it.