# KDE5 popup notifications not shown if panel is autohidden

Tags: kde, notification, kde5

All popup notifications are not shown in KDE5 session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workaround is to toggle of disable autohiding option on the panel.

The bug report: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=359693